# D3 Tick marks slightly off on xAxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

While creating a D3 Area Chart, I noticed that my X Axis tick marks are off shifted the the right just slightly:

[image]

For my code, I generate the xAxis like:

```
const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => Date.parse(d.date)))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3
        .axisBottom(x)
        .tickValues(data.map(d => {
            return timeParse(d.date);
        }))
            .tickFormat(timeFormat)
            .tickSizeOuter(0)
        )

svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong that is causing the tick marks to be slightly shifted to the right. If I don't include the `.tickSizeOuter(0)` part, the start and end tick marks look to be in normal spots but the data point ticks are still off.

How can I adjust these to be in the correct spot?

**EDIT**

Here is my data for this graph:

```
data = [
    {date: "2019-02-01", value: 100}, 
    {date: "2019-03-01", value: 1}]
]
```

And here is the `timeParse` var:

```
var timeParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

Answer (score 3):

You likely have a mix of UTC and local timezones. For the domain you use Date.parse(d.date). It assumes UTC timezone (because format is YYYY-MM-DD, new behavior starting with ES5) whereas d3.timeParse uses local time zone.
This may help:
[Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris and @Noleli stated in his above answer, I had a UTC/TimeZone mix up. So after looking into that a little bit, I found a new function that I can use. Instead of using `d3.timeParse` as my parse function:

```
var timeParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

D3 also provides a `d3.utcParse` parse function.

```
var timeParse = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

Using this provides the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data or `timeParse` it’s hard to know, but it could be a time zone issue. Try setting your computer to UTC and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I added the data and the timeParse for you. Time Zone shouldn't be of a factor because I am only parsing specific dates, not time